# GCC could not make 32bit executables?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gcc

i am installing asterisk server on my laptop with ubuntu 16.04 and gcc version 6.3.0 20170519 (Ubuntu/Linaro 6.3.0-18ubuntu2~16.04). by running following set of commands:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr --enable-shared --disable-sound --disable-resample --disable-video --disable-opencore-amr CFLAGS='O2 -DNDEBUG'
```

i get the following error:

```
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking target system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... no
aconfigure: error: in `/usr/src/asterisk-13.16.0/pjproject':
aconfigure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
```

config.log:

```
This file contains any messages produced by compilers while
running configure, to aid debugging if configure makes a mistake.

It was created by pjproject aconfigure 2.x, which was
generated by GNU Autoconf 2.69.  Invocation command line was

  $ ./aconfigure --prefix=/usr --enable-shared --disable-sound --disable-resample --disable-video --disable-opencore-amr CFLAGS=O2 -DNDEBUG

## --------- ##
## Platform. ##
## --------- ##

hostname = Linux-pc
uname -m = x86_64
uname -r = 4.4.0-75-generic
uname -s = Linux
uname -v = #96-Ubuntu SMP Thu Apr 20 09:56:33 UTC 2017

/usr/bin/uname -p = unknown
/bin/uname -X     = unknown

/bin/arch              = unknown
/usr/bin/arch -k       = unknown
/usr/convex/getsysinfo = unknown
/usr/bin/hostinfo      = unknown
/bin/machine           = unknown
/usr/bin/oslevel       = unknown
/bin/universe          = unknown

PATH: /usr/local/sbin
PATH: /usr/local/bin
PATH: /usr/sbin
PATH: /usr/bin
PATH: /sbin
PATH: /bin
PATH: /snap/bin


## ----------- ##
## Core tests. ##
## ----------- ##

aconfigure:2455: checking build system type
aconfigure:2469: result: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
aconfigure:2489: checking host system type
aconfigure:2502: result: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
aconfigure:2522: checking target system type
aconfigure:2535: result: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
aconfigure:2623: checking for gcc
aconfigure:2639: found /usr/bin/gcc
aconfigure:2650: result: gcc
aconfigure:2879: checking for C compiler version
aconfigure:2888: gcc --version >&5
gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 6.3.0-18ubuntu2~16.04) 6.3.0 20170519
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

aconfigure:2899: $? = 0
aconfigure:2888: gcc -v >&5
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu/Linaro 6.3.0-18ubuntu2~16.04' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-6/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,ada,c++,java,go,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-6 --program-prefix=x86_64-linux-gnu- --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=new --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-vtable-verify --enable-libmpx --enable-plugin --with-system-zlib --disable-browser-plugin --enable-java-awt=gtk --enable-gtk-cairo --with-java-home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-6-amd64/jre --enable-java-home --with-jvm-root-dir=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-6-amd64 --with-jvm-jar-dir=/usr/lib/jvm-exports/java-1.5.0-gcj-6-amd64 --with-arch-directory=amd64 --with-ecj-jar=/usr/share/java/eclipse-ecj.jar --with-target-system-zlib --enable-objc-gc=auto --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --enable-multilib --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 6.3.0 20170519 (Ubuntu/Linaro 6.3.0-18ubuntu2~16.04) 
aconfigure:2899: $? = 0
aconfigure:2888: gcc -V >&5
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-V'
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
aconfigure:2899: $? = 1
aconfigure:2888: gcc -qversion >&5
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-qversion'; did you mean '--version'?
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
aconfigure:2899: $? = 1
aconfigure:2919: checking whether the C compiler works
aconfigure:2941: gcc O2 -DNDEBUG   conftest.c  >&5
gcc: error: O2: No such file or directory
aconfigure:2945: $? = 1
aconfigure:2983: result: no
aconfigure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME "pjproject"
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME "pjproject"
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION "2.x"
| #define PACKAGE_STRING "pjproject 2.x"
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
| #define PACKAGE_URL ""
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| 
| int
| main ()
| {
| 
|   ;
|   return 0;
| }
aconfigure:2988: error: in `/usr/src/asterisk-13.16.0/pjproject':
aconfigure:2990: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details

## ---------------- ##
## Cache variables. ##
## ---------------- ##

ac_cv_build=x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
ac_cv_env_CCC_set=
ac_cv_env_CCC_value=
ac_cv_env_CC_set=
ac_cv_env_CC_value=
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_set=set
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_value='O2 -DNDEBUG'
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CPP_set=
ac_cv_env_CPP_value=
ac_cv_env_CXXFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CXXFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CXX_set=
ac_cv_env_CXX_value=
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_LIBS_set=
ac_cv_env_LIBS_value=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_value=
ac_cv_env_host_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_host_alias_value=
ac_cv_env_target_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_target_alias_value=
ac_cv_host=x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
ac_cv_prog_ac_ct_CC=gcc
ac_cv_target=x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu

## ----------------- ##
## Output variables. ##
## ----------------- ##

AR=''
AR_FLAGS=''
CC='gcc'
CC_CFLAGS=''
CC_DEF=''
CC_INC=''
CC_OPTIMIZE=''
CC_OUT=''
CFLAGS='O2 -DNDEBUG'
CPP=''
CPPFLAGS=''
CXX=''
CXXFLAGS='O2 -DNDEBUG '
DEFS=''
ECHO_C=''
ECHO_N='-n'
ECHO_T=''
EGREP=''
EXEEXT=''
GREP=''
LD=''
LDFLAGS=''
LDOUT=''
LIBEXT2=''
LIBEXT=''
LIBOBJS=''
LIBS=''
LTLIBOBJS=''
OBJEXT=''
PACKAGE_BUGREPORT=''
PACKAGE_NAME='pjproject'
PACKAGE_STRING='pjproject 2.x'
PACKAGE_TARNAME='pjproject'
PACKAGE_URL=''
PACKAGE_VERSION='2.x'
PATH_SEPARATOR=':'
PKG_CONFIG=''
RANLIB=''
SAVED_PKG_CONFIG_PATH=''
SDL_CONFIG=''
SHELL='/bin/bash'
ac_android_cflags=''
ac_build_mak_vars=''
ac_cross_compile=''
ac_ct_AR=''
ac_ct_CC='gcc'
ac_ct_CXX=''
ac_external_gsm=''
ac_external_pa=''
ac_external_speex=''
ac_external_srtp=''
ac_ffmpeg_cflags=''
ac_ffmpeg_ldflags=''
ac_has_ffmpeg=''
ac_host=''
ac_ios_cflags=''
ac_libyuv_cflags=''
ac_libyuv_ldflags=''
ac_linux_poll=''
ac_main_obj=''
ac_no_g711_codec=''
ac_no_g7221_codec=''
ac_no_g722_codec=''
ac_no_gsm_codec=''
ac_no_ilbc_codec=''
ac_no_l16_codec=''
ac_no_large_filter=''
ac_no_opencore_amrnb=''
ac_no_opencore_amrwb=''
ac_no_opus=''
ac_no_silk=''
ac_no_small_filter=''
ac_no_speex_aec=''
ac_no_speex_codec=''
ac_no_ssl=''
ac_openh264_cflags=''
ac_openh264_ldflags=''
ac_os_objs=''
ac_pa_cflags=''
ac_pa_use_alsa=''
ac_pa_use_oss=''
ac_pjdir=''
ac_pjmedia_audiodev_objs=''
ac_pjmedia_resample=''
ac_pjmedia_snd=''
ac_pjmedia_video=''
ac_pjmedia_video_has_android=''
ac_pjmedia_video_has_ios=''
ac_pjmedia_video_has_qt=''
ac_qt_cflags=''
ac_resample_dll=''
ac_sdl_cflags=''
ac_sdl_ldflags=''
ac_shared_libraries=''
ac_shlib_suffix=''
ac_srtp_deinit_present=''
ac_srtp_shutdown_present=''
ac_v4l2_cflags=''
ac_v4l2_ldflags=''
ac_webrtc_cflags=''
ac_webrtc_ldflags=''
bindir='${exec_prefix}/bin'
build='x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu'
build_alias=''
build_cpu='x86_64'
build_os='linux-gnu'
build_vendor='unknown'
datadir='${datarootdir}'
datarootdir='${prefix}/share'
docdir='${datarootdir}/doc/${PACKAGE_TARNAME}'
dvidir='${docdir}'
exec_prefix='NONE'
host='x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu'
host_alias=''
host_cpu='x86_64'
host_os='linux-gnu'
host_vendor='unknown'
htmldir='${docdir}'
includedir='${prefix}/include'
infodir='${datarootdir}/info'
libcrypto_present=''
libdir='${exec_prefix}/lib'
libexecdir='${exec_prefix}/libexec'
libssl_present=''
localedir='${datarootdir}/locale'
localstatedir='${prefix}/var'
mandir='${datarootdir}/man'
oldincludedir='/usr/include'
opencore_amrnb_h_present=''
opencore_amrnb_present=''
opencore_amrwb_dec_h_present=''
opencore_amrwb_dec_present=''
opencore_amrwb_enc_h_present=''
opencore_amrwb_enc_present=''
openssl_h_present=''
opus_h_present=''
opus_present=''
pdfdir='${docdir}'
prefix='/usr'
program_transform_name='s,x,x,'
psdir='${docdir}'
sbindir='${exec_prefix}/sbin'
sharedstatedir='${prefix}/com'
silk_h_present=''
silk_present=''
sysconfdir='${prefix}/etc'
target='x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu'
target_alias=''
target_cpu='x86_64'
target_os='linux-gnu'
target_vendor='unknown'

## ----------- ##
## confdefs.h. ##
## ----------- ##

/* confdefs.h */
#define PACKAGE_NAME "pjproject"
#define PACKAGE_TARNAME "pjproject"
#define PACKAGE_VERSION "2.x"
#define PACKAGE_STRING "pjproject 2.x"
#define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
#define PACKAGE_URL ""

aconfigure: exit 77
```

i have tried following solutions to solve this issue:

1) install updated version of GCC and G++ again

2) apt-get install libc6-dev:i386 gcc:i386
it returns:

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gcc:i386 : Depends: cpp:i386 (>= 4:5.3.1-1ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: gcc-5:i386 (>= 5.3.1-3~) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

3) apt-get install gcc-multilib shows that it is already installed

4) apt-get install lib32gcc-4.8-dev installed successfully

5) by compiling a simple test file using gcc test.c -m32 -o test returns:

```
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6/libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6/libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

still i am not able to get rid of this problem. any help??

Comment: for the first error, whatever program tried to generate the command messed up. Probably there is something misconfigured at some point: the `-` of `-O2` options is missing in the line that has 2941 in it.

Comment: `CFLAGS='O2` O2 is not a correct C or C++ compiler flag, -O2 is.